# I am having difficulties deploying a Swing Application via Web Start/Applet

Tags: java, swing, jnlp

I have constructed a Swing Application that needs to be run from a browser. Here is the code for the HTML file, JNLP file, and the Swing Applications Code. Is there a clear reason why this is not working?

Its posted at www.nestroia.com/netbeans.html

Thanks, all help is greatly appreciated.

### HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame 
        Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

        <title>Nestroia.com</title>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="author" content="Artur Vieira" />

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />

         <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and
         delete these references -->
         <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
         <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
     </head>
     <body>
         <script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
         <script> 
         var attributes = { code:'NetBeans_SwingFrame',  width:800, height:600} ; 
         var parameters = {jnlp_href: 'NetBeans_SwingFrame.jnlp'} ; 
         deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6'); 
         </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

### JNLP

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
        <information>
            <title>NetBeans_SwingFrame</title>
            <vendor>Nestroia.com</vendor>
        </information>
        <resources>
            <!-- Application Resources -->
            <j2se version="1.6+"
              href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
            <jar href="NetBeans_SwingFrame.jar" main="true" />

        </resources>
        <applet-desc 
            name="NetBeans_SwingFrame"
            main-class="netbeans_swingframe.NetBeans_SwingFrame"
            width="800"
            height="600">
        </applet-desc>
        <update check="background"/>
    </jnlp>
```

### Java

```
    public class NetBeans_SwingFrame extends JFrame{
        public NetBeans_SwingFrame(){
            setTitle("Nestroia");
            setSize(800,600);
            setLocation(0,0);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setVisible(true);

            JLabel text = new JLabel("This is where the Application goes.");
            this.getContentPane().add(text,BorderLayout.NORTH);

     }
     /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
     public static void main(String[] args) {
           NetBeans_SwingFrame main = new NetBeans_SwingFrame();
     }
    }
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean, specifically?

Comment: If you're launching via JNLP then you don't have an applet, you're using Web Start.

Comment: It gives me a error, it's brief and doesn't give me much information. It just says that "There was an error while executing the application"

Comment: @Paul It's the new way to deploy applets with a better sandbox, you must link to a JNLP file

Comment: @Paul http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html

Comment: Incidentally, Swing GUI objects should be constructed and manuipulated _only_ on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) in both applets and applications.

Comment: @trashgod Please explain

Comment: What's not clear in the linked tutorial?

Comment: @trahgod I read the tutorial and I am still a little unsure of what to do.

Comment: Use `invokeLater()` in `main()`; of you're still unsure, pose a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I notice is that a `JFrame` should be launched using an `application-desc` in the JNLP, rather than an `applet-desc`.  But for a far better validation than my eye can supply, use [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

---

It would also help immensely if you were to answer aardvarkk's question to explain *What does "not working" mean, specifically?*

Comment: It gives me a error, it's brief and doesn't give me much information. It just says that "There was an error while executing the application"

Answer (score 2):

**NetBenas_SwingFrame**

Typo isn't it (main-class).